# How can I display widget in a Page or Post?

Tags: posts, pages, widgets

I am trying to display some widgets (Quora & Goodreads) widgets inside Page or Post. How do I do that without displaying it inside Sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this. Many plugins that provide a widget *also* provide a 
shortcode (text in brackets that you can put in your post like this: [quora]). I have no idea whether either of your widgets also come with shortcodes.

Though I've never used them, there are some plugins that claim to help you do this. (Like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-on-pages/).)

If there isn't a shortcode and you can't find a plugin, your last option is to [write your own shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that runs [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget). You'll need some low- to moderate-PHP ability to do this. I've never tried it, so I can't say whether there are any caveats to this solution. With a quick google search, I was able to find [this tutorial](http://wpfirstaid.com/tag/add_shortcode/) for making a shortcode that runs `the_widget()`. Good luck!

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response and answer. That was really helpful. Like you said, there are plugins that provide shortcode for me to use and there are some that are not. I'll try and see if I'll manage to make it to work. Thanks for the wish!

Answer (score 1):

Widgets, by design, are to be used in the sidebar.  If you want widgets in your page or post, you've got two options: rewrite the code to work in a template, or register a sidebar inside the page or post template.  Sidebars do not have to be on the side, after all.

Comment: I am have limited background with coding but I'm open to experiment and trying things, so I'll look how I can get em to work.

That makes a lot of senses! Maybe I should register a sidebar inside a page as a workaround.

Thanks!